# Can't find the USB port that USBasp programer is using in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, 22.04, serial-port

I'm trying to set up everything to make some projects using Atmega microcontroller. The problem starts when I'm trying to flash compiled program to microcontroller because I need to specify port on which my USBasp is connected. The command goes like this, for example.

`avrdude -c usbasp -p m32 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 19200 -U flash:w:led.hex`

This `-P` parameter which is port should look something like this `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but there is nothing like that in the `/dev` directory.

[image]

What is even worse is that when I plug in or unplug my USBasp programmer nothing at all changes when I list everything in `/dev` using `ls` command. If I unplug my mouse for example and plug it in again every time `ls` command reacts to changes, but nothing at all with my USBasp programmer.

[image]

I don't think that its broken coz other commands do recognize it for example `lsusb`

[image]

I have tried everything Google throws at me, but I just cant seem to find this port to specify when writing data using programmer. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

When I run `sudo journalctl --follow` device is getting recognized and I'm getting this information, but it doesn't do anything good because it doesn't give me this path `/dev/ttyUSB*` or something similar.

[image]

When I run `ls -1 /dev >dev.before` and `ls -1 /dev >dev.after` there were absolutely 0 difference between those files.

When I'm running this command `udevadm monitor --property` and adding programmer I'm getting this text that repeats itself with little differences 3 times.

```
UDEV  [1624.578178] add       
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb) ACTION=add  
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0  
SUBSYSTEM=usb DEVTYPE=usb_interface PRODUCT=16c0/5dc/102 TYPE=255/0/0  
INTERFACE=0/0/0  
MODALIAS=usb:v16C0p05DCd0102dcFFdsc00dp00ic00isc00ip00in00 SEQNUM=3937  
USEC_INITIALIZED=1624577910 ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific  
Class ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Van Ooijen Technische Informatica  
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=shared ID for use with libusb  
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0  
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0  
  
UDEV  [1624.585799] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2  
(usb) ACTION=bind DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2  
SUBSYSTEM=usb DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/021 DEVTYPE=usb_device  
DRIVER=usb PRODUCT=16c0/5dc/102 TYPE=255/0/0 BUSNUM=001 DEVNUM=021  
SEQNUM=3938 USEC_INITIALIZED=1624574304 ID_VENDOR=www.fischl.de  
ID_VENDOR_ENC=www.fischl.de ID_VENDOR_ID=16c0 ID_MODEL=USBasp  
ID_MODEL_ENC=USBasp ID_MODEL_ID=05dc ID_REVISION=0102  
ID_SERIAL=www.fischl.de_USBasp ID_BUS=usb ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Van  
Ooijen Technische Informatica ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=shared ID for use  
with libusb ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2  
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2  
ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2 MAJOR=189 MINOR=20  
TAGS=:uaccess:seat: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:
```

I was hoping that `DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0` this could be the "port", but there is no such a thing as , `/devices` directory.

I used `avrdude -P usb` to specify port and it worked. I'm glad it does, but still would be interesting to know why I couldn't find the port path for this controller. I found the answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312384/usbasp-not-creating-ttyusb0).

Comment: ttyACM and ttyS are common devices to try, I would also look at the first to see if te kernel found a tty

Comment: You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`. Then, look at the system logs `sudo journalctl /dev/devicename`.

Comment: can you check udev rules of atmega8 using this command `udevadm monitor --property`? if it is not there, you need to create new udev rules. check this https://www.fischl.de/usbasp/ .

Comment: Ty guys, ill check everything when ill get to work

Comment: i edited my question guys

Comment: You should move your last edit into an answer, and then accept it. As the link you added says, this device isn't a fully compliant serial port, so the kernel cannot create a `/dev/ttyACM0` or similar, as it wouldn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `avrdude -P usb` to specify port and it worked. I found the answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312384/usbasp-not-creating-ttyusb0).

Here is the screenshot of original answer

[image]